# Average a Month's worth of NetCDF data to one 24hr-day to give the mean diurnal cycle

Tags: python, time, netcdf, cdo-climate

I hope you're well --

I have multiple files all having one month of hourly data.

```
Wind = Jun1.variables['wind'][:,:,:]
Wind = Jun2.variables['winds'][:,:,:]
etc
```

Below shows the dimensions

I want to average each individual files in a way to calculate the hourly average to get the diurnal cycle for each month with array shape (time, lon, lat) of 24 steps.

Comment: I rephrased the question according to our interpretation for clarity, but please change if my edits have changed the nature of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compute the mean diurnal cycle from a month of hourly data. NCO's [ncra](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#interleave) does this with a feature called "interleaving":

```
ncra -d time,,,,720,24 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

If Charlie's interpretation is correct (I think it is from your desired array shape) then you can work out the diurnal cycle over a multi day period with CDO using

```
cdo dhourmean in.nc out.nc
```

I think you need to make sure you have a recent version of cdo for this. v1.9.5 should be okay.

EDIT Oct 2021: I've just launched [a video on this topic on my climate unboxed channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKlA1ouoQIs&t=8s) to provide more details on calculating diurnal cycles.

Comment: I was about to suggest a way to chain this with mergetime, but surprisingly CDO does not seem to have a method for this. Though I guess people rarely deal with hourly stats

Comment: Ah I see ok I'm working on other data currently. I looked into http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html too. it seems NCO or CDO. I also need to convert UTC to local time to then do this calculation since its over an entire US map

Comment: well that's another question, but you can use **cdo shifttime**